# How to prevent screen captures in the Electron app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Due to security reasons I need to prevent taking screenshots in my app. App gets built both for windows and for macOS so it needs to be prevented on both platforms.

Comment: You won't be able to stop the user from taking a screenshot from outside the app, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Screenshots are not controlled by the web browser, they are controlled by software running on the user's operating system and cannot be remotely controlled by a web server.

Comment: @Tholle That's what I meant. Wasn't sure if I can somehow disable default mac's and windows's screen capture while my desktop Electron app is running.

Comment: You can use global shortcuts to "override" the printscreen key, but the user can still use the screencap tool build-in the OS (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut)

Comment: @brklja did you found a solution?

Comment: @Suhayb Unfortunately no...

Answer (score 13):

Electron offers the following method of BrowserWindow : setContentProtection
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetcontentprotectionenable-macos-windows

Call that method on your main window or any window you want protected from screenshots.
Supports MacOS and Windows